# Difference between groupids net.sf.jasperreports and jasperreports

Tags: maven, jasper-reports

I was using `net.sf.jasperreports` as the group for the version 3.6.0.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For some reasons, I was asked to downgrade to the version 3.5.2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When I have taken a build it is observed that some of the jar files are missing like,

```
jcommon-1.0.15.jar 
jdtcore-3.1.0.jar
```

Can anyone please explain me why this is happening. Are these jars are coming from `net.sf.jasperreports`? Please explain the difference between using groupids `jasperreports` and `net.sf.jasperreports`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is an inheritance from older maven conventions. The name of the groupId is merely an identifier and as such it only really has to be unique in the context it is being used. Se also http://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg34557.html

That means that as long as you don't use any dependencies outside of your own local repository (and stay offline), you could duplicate names of dependencies in maven central, for instance junit, primefaces or whatever.

So version 3.5.2 of jasperreports simply used artifactId as groupId (or vice versa), but later versions changed groupId to net.sf.jasperreports.

Dependencies between versions change, so it's pretty natural some artifacts "disappear" if you downgrade. If your project depends on these artifacts, you should explicitly define these as dependencies in your POM.

Comment: Does these missing jars make any impact on the application?

Comment: Unless you specifically need them for your own code, no they shouldn't.